# Cloud build: substitutions in `substitutions` section?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

#### 2019-07-04: Update

Ended up using

```sh
options:
   env:
```

Not perfect since doesn't allow variable in build steps but atleast environments are covered.

### Problem

GCP's `Cloud build` is not substituting variables in `substitutions` section.

Is there a way to have those substitutions applied?

#### Example snippet

```
substitutions:
  _HUGO_VERSION: "0.55.6"
  _HUGO_IMG: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hugo:$_HUGO_VERSION
```

#### Expectation

To have `$_HUGO_VERSION` and `$PROJECT_ID` replaced with values, to get:

```
_HUGO_IMG=gcr.io/foo/hugo:0.55.6
```

#### Actual

But the value for `_HUGO_IMG` is taken literally:

```
_HUGO_IMG=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hugo:$_HUGO_VERSION
```

Answer (score 9):

Your expected behavior is now supported. Please see the documentation:
[Using payload bindings and bash-style string operations in substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions)

```
options:
    dynamic_substitutions: true
substitutions:
    _HUGO_IMG: gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hugo:${_HUGO_VERSION}
```

Comment: It seems that `${PROJECT_ID}` works but `$PROJECT_ID` doesn't

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for posting this!

Could you post the full config, when I try this I get an error for using `=` instead of `:` when declaring the substitutions.

The behavior I see instead is:

```
hugo version: 0.55.6
hugo img: gcr.io//hugo:
```

To interpolate default or custom substitutions, I suggest using env variables instead

```
steps:
- id: 'checking sub values'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    echo 'hugo version: '${_HUGO_VERSION} # hugo version: 0.55.6
    echo 'hugo img: '${_HUGO_IMG} # hugo img: gcr.io//hugo:
    echo 'env hugo img: '$$HUGO_IMG # env hugo img: 'gcr.io/my-project/hugo:0.55.6'
substitutions:
    _HUGO_VERSION: "0.55.6"
    _HUGO_IMG: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hugo:$_HUGO_VERSION'
options:
    env:
    - HUGO_IMG='gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hugo:$_HUGO_VERSION'
```

Note that env vars need to be used with `$$`

Comment: fixed the `=` typo. 
I have many steps and repeating same `HUGO_IMG=...` in `env:` gets cumbersome fast.

Comment: agreed! env variables can be set for the entire build under `options:` (-:

Comment: Thanks! That's an improvement!