# Including default substitutions inside other `substitutions`

Tags: yaml, google-cloud-build

From here... https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

I am trying to use substitutions inside my `cloudbuild.yaml` file but almost all my substitutions depend on the project ID of the project I am deploying to.

I have my yaml file like this...

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'functionName', ...other args... , '--service-account', '${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}', '--source', '${_SOURCE_REPO}']
substitutions:
  _SOURCE_REPO: 'https://source.developers.google.com/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repos/my-repo-id/moveable-aliases/master/paths/functions/src'
  _SERVICE_ACCOUNT: 'blah@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

And whatever I try with the substitutions (I have tried both formats `$_FOO` and `${_FOO}`) and what I end up with is `blah@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with the `${PROJECT_ID}` text still in there rather than it having the actual project ID.

If I move the text into the step and just use it instead of the substitution then it works. But ideally I'd like to use this method as these values will be used a lot so would like to save repetition.

## EDIT

Well, I've tried a few different options including some of the suggestions that @ralemos mentioned but nothing seems to be working.

If I use this format...

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'functionName', ...other args... , '--service-account', '${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}', '--source', '${SOURCE_REPO}']
options:
  env:
    SOURCE_REPO: 'https://source.developers.google.com/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/repos/my-repo-id/moveable-aliases/master/paths/functions/src'
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT: 'blah@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

It complains that the env lines are invalid.

If I use this format...

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'functionName', ...other args... , '--service-account', '${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}', '--source', '${SOURCE_REPO}']
options:
  env:
    'SOURCE_REPO=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/repos/my-repo-id/moveable-aliases/master/paths/functions/src'
    'SERVICE_ACCOUNT=blah@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

It complains that `SERVICE_ACCOUNT` and `SOURCE_REPO` are not valid built-in substitutions.

If I use `$$SOURCE_REPO` as the syntax it just replaces it with `$SOURCE_REPO` rather than using the substitution.

It seems for now that what I'm trying just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use env variables instead of substitutions, as you can see on the answer of this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800591/cloud-build-substitutions-in-substitutions-section).

The result would be something like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'functionName', ...other args... , '--service-account', '${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}', '--source', '${SOURCE_REPO}']
options:
  env:
    SOURCE_REPO: 'https://source.developers.google.com/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/repos/my-repo-id/moveable-aliases/master/paths/functions/src'
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT: 'blah@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: The `project-name` is a default substitution. I want to get that from the value passed to me. Otherwise I'd have to go in and edit it every time I use it.

Comment: What if you use the default substitution in the env variable then? that way you would not need a substitution tag at all.

Comment: that’s what I was doing. That doesn’t work either. I don’t think the $$ syntax in that other question was correct.

Comment: Indeed, $$ would only add a $ in front of the value of the variable itself. In that case, try what I edited the answer into, it should work

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: I thought you might be onto something there but alas it wasn't so. Still not able to get this working. Will have to resort to just having the repeated lines in there. Or potentially... generating the file on the fly and using another script to change the values in it.